# Unlink() error permission denied

Tags: php

```
if (file_exists("./a.php")) {
    chmod('a.php', 0777);
    unlink("./a.php");
}
```

não entendo porque ainda da erro no meu código, já dei as permissões via terminal linux com chmod 777 mas continua sem funcionar, tento com o php e não da.

os erros são chmod() operação não permitida in ... e unlink('/a.php') operação negada in...

Comment: Por favor, explique melhor seu problema, está muito vago.

Comment: editei a questão

Comment: quando vocÊ roda o comando como terminal você esta usando o usuário root ou grupo sudo, quando roda pelo apache, e outro usuário,

Comment: uso o usuario root

Comment: um diretório acima da pasta aonde está tentando criar esse arquivo roda o comando `ls -aos` e posta o resultado.

Comment: 4 drwxr-xr-x 6 pedro 4096 jan 25 09:59 alunos

Comment: a pasta se chama alunos, onde to tentando apagar um arquivo

Comment: Seu objetivo é apenas apagar o `a.php` ou tem que apagar com uso do `php` ?

Comment: Quero apagar com o uso do php, para poder criar uma função que apaga os arquivos, ai to fazendo um teste pra apagar esse.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88791/discussion-between-pedro-henrique-and-bulfaitelo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que conversamos no [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88791/discussion-between-pedro-henrique-and-bulfaitelo), parece que seu problema era relacionado a permissão do diretório.

Para solucionar isso definimos o diretório com a permissão 777, rodando o comando `chmod 777 ../alunos` dentro do diretório alunos.

Referencia:
https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/artigo/Entendento-o-comando-chmod